# Como configurar um sub-domínio no Azure

Tags: microsoft-azure

Tenho uma aplicação no seguinte endereço `myapp.azurewebsites.net`. Registrei um novo dominio `mydom.srv.net` e configurei o CNAME no Registro.br conforme documentação. Tudo ok ao acessar `mydom.srv.net`!!!

Agora, como posso configurar um sub-domínio (ex. api) `api.mydom.srv.net`? Tentei incluir um novo CNAME valor `api` para `myapp.azurewebsites.net/api` mas recebo uma mensagem de erro (nome de servidor inválido).

Answer (score 1):

Se a sua intenção é utilizar `api.mydom.srv.net` basta criar o DNS no Registro.BR (ou qualquer outro DNS) da seguinte forma

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entretanto, se você quer acessar `myapp.azurewebsites.net/api` ou `mydom.srv.net/api` não existe necessidade de criar uma entrada no DNS, pois este acesso deve ser feito via aplicação e não nível DNS.